# If Linux runs well on a laptop, will BSD run too?

Tags: bsd

Is it a safe bet to assume that if Linux runs well (boot parameters not needed, everything (wifi, bluetooth, etc) works) in a laptop, BSD will run well too?

Comment: Ther is no relationship between the two things. BSD has less support and you may find no driver for some devices of your laptop. Check official documents.

Comment: You're not telling what BSD you plan to run. FWIW, OpenBSD's bluetooth stack is a state of the art implementation, the BEST in the whole industry.

Answer (score 11):

> Is it a safe bet to assume...

Not trying to be pedantic or flippant, but it's not to safe to assume anything in technology (or even in life, for that matter).

If something runs in one distribution of Linux, there's no guarantee that it will run in another.  Bring in a completely different OS and, as you put it, all bets are off!

BSD ≠ Linux; both are *very* different.  One of the very strong points in favor of BSD (FreeBSD in particular) is the documentation.  Specific to this question; [the hardware compatibility list](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/faq/hardware.html)

Bluetooth and WiFi have been "sore spots" with respect to compatibility, but they are making some good strides.  I have found excellent support with both Broadcom and Intel chipsets.  If you're looking to architect a system that has excellent BSD support, start with the HCL specific to the release (i.e. [12.1 HCL](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/12.1R/hardware.html)) and build from there.

If you're looking at a particular laptop, get the specs, then compare it to the HCL to see what's supported and what's not.  There's also an excellent section of the [FreeBSD Wiki for WiFi](https://wiki.freebsd.org/WiFi) (and other hardware) support.  From personal experience, the Dell Latitude line has been excellent (for me) as a workstation platform with everything supported from WiFi, Bluetooth and track pad all being supported.